# MySQL TRIGGER for REPLACE query

Tags: mysql, triggers

I need to insert some data in my log table in situation, when after my REPLACE query one of my field was changed from value1 to value2.  I wrote a trigger which compares the same filed in NEW and OLD rows. But NEW is not available in this case, because I triggered DELETE action (REPLACE event emits delete event). Is any other way to know OLD and NEW rows of one field after REPLACE query?

Comment: MySQL or Oracle ? You're having conflicting tags ...